# Syntax error in AWS lambda function when trying to return a multiple line JSON file

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[image]

I am getting a syntax error whenever I attempt to return a json file that is longer than 2 lines in my Lambda function. For example this code will not run and gives the error: 
[image]

But then once I comment out one line like so:[image]

Then the function runs perfectly. 
[image]

Any ideas on what I could be doing incorrectly? I'm not very experienced with JSON.

Comment: You need to separate the two elements of your `dataReturn` dict with a comma, just as you did with the two elements of the dict being returned.

Comment: Post code and errors as text, NOT as screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing out a comma "," at the end of the first line.

it should be like this

```
dataReturn = {
    'Type' : eventStr[eventStr.index("Type")+8 : eventStr.index("EventId")-4],
'Time' : str(eventStr[eventStr.index("Timestamp")+13 : eventStr.index("Job")-4])
}
```